# Consequence of order in a classification (top N list which is ordered by mark)

Tags: survey

I refer to all the kind of lists which are presented in a particular order, imagining a situation in which users respond to these lists by adding their votes.

Let's make some example:
http://area51.stackexchange.com/
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio
http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
http://www.pcmag.com/reviews/software

They are usually called top 10, top 25, top 100 but they are not always of a fixed number. The order is usually fixed and related to a numeric parameter which is not intrinsic to the item itself but attributed by users through a voting system.

Those systems are thought to measure the user interest but they are completely biased after the first users express their +1 vote. Since of the presentation order.

That parameter which we may call mark or "score function" is usually intended to measure the value of the item itself in a subjective way. The classical +1 may be an example.

The items can be almost everything: movies, one feature for the future release of a software, a community.

The first element of the list have an higher visibility and this has a strong bias, when we would assume that the first elements of list are the more valuable, more requested, more supported and so on. Since human being are usually not going to examine the whole list but only the first elements. So the elements which are presented for first in the list get an advantage and are likely to stay in the first position almost forever.

How is possible to take track of this factor and eliminate the bias in score due to the higher visibility of the first elements due to the fixed presentation order? Is it possible to measure, through data mining for example, the influence of being in the first page or in the second and try to give a bias corrected score to the items in the following pages?

Comment: (The example you point to on SE does not seem to conform to your characterization: there, site proposals are ordered by *recency*, not by "highest voted to the lowest."  And that's not a survey, anyway.)  What do you mean by "individual score" and "favorite requests"?  How is that related to information typically returned by surveys?

Comment: @whuber: mmm.. I didn't realize that. I see them sorted by "progress". But I don't know exactly how that variable is defined.. However you can find another example here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio, in any case, every time we introduce a sorting we influence the  user's opinion. Or better to say: the probability of having a user clicking something at page 50 is lower than having a user clicking something at page 1. Which introduce a bias in the measurement of the user's opinion. I used the word survey since I don't know exactly how to define this kind of list

Comment: Certainly presentation order will influence reader responses: that is why the order of presentation is always randomized when response bias is a concern.  But "survey" has a fairly specific meaning in statistics, so it would be well for you to edit the question to clarify what you mean by this term. It still is not apparent what you mean by "score," "requests," or even "favorite."

Comment: @whuber: I've tried to completely rewrite the question, can you have a look to see if it's more clear now?

Comment: It's much clearer, thank you (+1). It seems, though, to be missing any definite sense of what is meant by "bias." You appear to be thinking of a situation in which users respond to these lists by adding their votes, but this is nowhere stated.  Incidentally, to your examples of such lists you might add the lists of answers that appear in all StackExchange threads!

Comment: @whuber: thanks, I've changed some parts to improve even more the text and trying to make it more clear. I really appreciate the help you gave me I didn't realize how hard was to understand what I meant. This systems are thought to measure the user interest but they are completely biased after the first users express their +1 vote. Since of the presentation order.